# Find non-duplicate records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, unique, multiple-tables

I searched though the internet but could not found what i was looking for, may be because i dont know what to search.

My problem is to get non-duplicate records from multiple tables...

Say if i have two tables as follows,

```
tableA
----------------------
code    ip
1       111.168.1.2
2       111.222.333.333
3       111.168.1.2
4       111.234.2.44
5       111.23.455.44

tableB
----------------------
code    ip                 ISP
1       111.222.333.333    newtwo
2       111.168.2.2        anon
3       111.333.453.567    def
4       111.168.2.2        tele
5       111.222.333.333    new
6       111.333.544.3      ispnew
```

What i expect to get out of this is,

```
ip
111.234.2.44
111.23.455.44
111.333.453.567
143.333.544.3
```

I have tried UNION, DISTICNT and DISTINCT AND UNION together like so,

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP FROM(SELECT IP FROM tableA UNION SELECT IP FROM tableB)
```

But it gives all the values unique an duplicate as follows,

```
ip
111168.1.2
111.222.333.333
111.234.2.44
111.23.455.44
111.168.2.2 
111.333.453.567     
111.333.544.3
```

Please help me on this one, I will be much great-full..THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DISTINCT` give every entry just once but doesn't throw out the duplicate ones completely. what you'll have to to is using `GROUP BY`, `COUNT` and `HAVING` to get rid of those:

```
SELECT
  IP
FROM
  (
    SELECT IP FROM tableA
  UNION ALL
    SELECT IP FROM tableB
  )
GROUP BY
  IP
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Got me by a bunch of seconds :'(

Comment: yessss..thankyou very much!!!! it works!! :) this is exactly what i was looking for :) il accept it as the answer in 3 minutes, dt what was said when i tried to mark it :)

Comment: Hey..sorry for bothering, may i know if i could speed up this process...i have lyk 6000 records to be matched and this takes some time :) thank a bunch :)

Comment: I don't think there is any further scope for optimizing this query. `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` makes it faster. Still you can add `ORDER BY NULL` clause in this query.

Comment: okey.. thank you very much for your reply.ill try those out..very much appreciated :)